# FastAPI - Get websocket route name within view function

Tags: python, fastapi

How does one extract the route name (Flask equivalent of endpoint) within the associated view? Consider the following:

```
@ws_app.websocket("/route1", name="endpoint2")
@ws_app.websocket("/route2", name="endpoint2")
async def main_stream(ws: WebSocket):
    if [reference to name?] == 'endpoint1':
        ... act on /route1 request ....
```

It's not quite clear from the documentation how this is done, attempts to access various properties from `ws` (e.g., `scope`) didn't help. Any advice?

Comment: When you define the endpoint, don't you already know it's name? Do you mind providing an example?

Comment: endpoint definitions allow you to respond to different routes within a view function, i've edited the example to address this.

Comment: maybe you can compare with `request.url` ?